# I don't understand why this circuit works with MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet

[image]

This circuit works, Vgs = 12V, when IN1 = 0V the circuit lets pass an external current that comes from A and goes out through OUT1, for them to happen the voltage between gate and source must be 12V, but the source is not at any voltage (it's actually floating), so why is there 12V between gate and source? to my understanding this circuit should not work but it works

Comment: Please edit the diagram and show what is on the A- terminal and OUT1 terminal.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Vgs = 12v regardless of whether or not current passes from A to OUT

Comment: @RicardoCasimiro You say "*the circuit lets pass an external current that comes from A and goes out through OUT1*" -- this means thare is *something* connected to `OUT1`. You need to show what. If there is nothing, there can't be any current flowing to `OUT1`. At the very least, you have to say what potential is at the drain of `Q5`. Otherwise, it looks like DKNguyen's answer is the good one.

Comment: could you crop your screenshot to the relevant part and describe the problem rather than the fact that you're confused in the title? That'd be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When IN1 = 0, current flows from +24V through R5 then R9 then through Q5's body diode to ground. That makes the divider R5 and R8 have a voltage of \$\frac{24V - V_d}{2} \approx ~12V\$. See that little diode in the MOSFET symbol? It's not there for no reason. Almost all discrete MOSFETs have that.

Comment: The diode of Q5 is not connected to ground at any time

Comment: @RicardoCasimiroIh Oh, You're right. I don't know what my eyes were seeing. What is connected to OUT1? Is this simulation or real?